# How to distribute an application that relies on DLL's for 32-bit and 64-bit machines

Tags: java, ant, desktop-application, native-code

I have an application that uses a 3rd party jar (utils.jar), which calls a 3rd party DLL (utils.dll). The jar file manages calls to DLL including the name of the DLL. There is a 32-bit version and a 64-bit version of the DLL.

Currently, the application can only run on 32-bit machines. When I try to run it on a 64-bit machine, it tells me

```
Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

When I replace the 32-bit dll with the 64-bit, it works fine. I don't want to maintain two separate releases if I can avoid it (one using 32-bit library, the other using 64-bit library). Is there a way to build the application so that it can figure out which version of the library it needs to use?

Our projects are built using Ant, though I can explore other alternatives if necessary.

Comment: The hacky way would be to bundle both JARs or DLLs as a resource, and place the right one on the PATH when your application starts before the third-party JAR loads it. Assuming your application can write to the filesystem at will.

Comment: Is this a desktop app.?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an additonal ant target such that it builds always a x32 and a x64 variant of your application.

> I don't want to maintain two separate releases

If the ant your skript always produce both deliverys that its not much addional effort.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how I would specify the 32-bit and 64-bit variants? I am looking through the ant docs but not sure how it would be written.

Comment: I would define an additional classpath/libraries class path named x64Classpath, ther you include the x64 hard. Then instead the :jar target an :jar32 and an jar64 taregt where you use the x64 libraries path / class path

Answer (score 1):

When you do loadLibary you could compose the library name with the `System.getProperty("os.arch")`. So, you bundle all dlls, and the related version will be chosen at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)<sup>1</sup>.  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

1. > JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), **partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture** or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..